# how to get blocked file extensions and maximum file size for attachment in dynamics crm using c# code

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I want to get blocked file extension and maximum file size for attachment set by admin in c# code .Below image displays what I actually want using c# code.

[image]

[image]

Please suggest me answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below code, it is tested and working fine.

```
 var  query = new QueryExpression("organization")
                {
                    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("blockedattachments", "maxuploadfilesize")
                };
                var record = service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities.FirstOrDefault();

                if (record != null)
                {
                    var blockedAttachments = record.GetAttributeValue<string>("blockedattachments");
                    var maxAttachmentSize = record.GetAttributeValue<int>("maxuploadfilesize");
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following code to get any property in the `System Settings`.

```
var query = new QueryExpression("organization")
          {
                ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("blockedattachments", "maxuploadfilesize")

           };
           EntityCollection orgCollection = _service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
           if (orgCollection.Entities.Count > 0)
           {
           Entity org = orgCollection.Entities.First();
           string blockedattachments = org.GetAttributeValue<string>("blockedattachments");
           int numberMaxUploadFileSize = org.GetAttributeValue<int>("maxuploadfilesize");
           }
```